# How to improve depth segmentation of Lego blocks

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, depth, realsense

##### Input

I have the following **depth images**  of type `uint16` obtained from **Intel realsense [L515](https://www.intelrealsense.com/download/7691)** camera which is supposed to have an `Avg Depth Accuracy< 5mm @ 1m`.

[image: d1]

[image: d2]

##### Goal

I want to **quantify the depth of the blocks** inside this image to get a discrete representation of the blocks inside my region of interest of `23 x 11 block positions` such as

`P_x1_y1 : z = 1`(one block), `P_x2_y2: z = 2` (two blocks), up to 5 blocks (as in the image center).

The **ROI RGB** Image can clarify my aim *(but it is not used as an input)*:

[image: roi]

##### What I have tried so far:

1. Obtaining the **ROI**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_roi(d1, output_size=(736, 384), ratio=(0.77, 0.54), shift=(0, 80), verbose=False):
    """
    Function: get_roi, to find and resize the ROI.
    ---
    Parameters:
    @param: d1, nd array, depth image.
    @param: output_size, tuple, the output ROI size.
    @param: ratio, tuple, the ratio of the ROI to the detected zone.
    @param: shift, tuple, the shift in pixles to align the ROI.
    @param: verbose, bool, to vizualize the result.
    ---
    @return: roi, nd array, ROI resized.
    """
    d = d1.copy()

    th =  cv2.threshold(d, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    th = th.astype(np.uint8)

    contours = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )[0]
    cnt_thresh = 10000
    fx, fy = ratio
    x_shift, y_shift = shift
    for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
        if(cv2.contourArea(cnt)>cnt_thresh):
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            cx = x + w//2 + x_shift
            cy = y + h//2 + y_shift
            nw = int(fx * w)
            nh = int(fy * h)
            # cv2.rectangle(d1,(cx-nw//2,cy-nh//2),(cx+nw//2,cy+nh//2),color=0)
    d_roi = d1[cy-nh//2:cy+nh//2,cx-nw//2:cx+nw//2]
    roi = cv2.resize(d_roi, output_size)

    # Visualize results
    if(verbose):
        plt.imshow(roi)
        plt.show()

    return roi
```

2. Finding the **mode(most frequent) non-zero** value of each cell in the grid:

```py
def mode(arr):
    """
    Function: mode, to find the mode of an array.
    ---
    Parameters:
    @param: arr, nd array, any.
    ---
    @return: the mode value (whatever int/float/etc) of this array.
    """
    vals,counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
    if 0 in vals:
        z_idx = np.where(vals == 0)
        vals   = np.delete(vals,   z_idx)
        counts = np.delete(counts, z_idx)
    index = np.argmax(counts)
    return vals[index]
```

3. Quantifying the values of each cell:

```py
def mapVal(val):
    """
    Function: mapVal, to map depth values.
    ---
    Parameters:
    @param: val, int, any.
    ---
    @return: int val, specific value 0, 50, 150, 200, 250, val.
    """
    if val<=183:
        return 0
    if val>183 and val <=230:
        return 50
    if val>230 and val <=295:
        return 100
    if val>295 and val <=390:
        return 150
    if val>390 and val <=470:
        return 200
    if val>470:
        return 250
    else:
        return val
```

4. **grid the ROI** into cells, and applying **Linear correction** for the depth static error:

```py
def gridWorkspace(roi, gridSize=(23, 11), shift=[0, 5], verbose=False):
    """
    Function: gridWorkspace, to find the contours of the red markers.
    ---
    Parameters:
    @param: roi, nd array, cropped region of interest.
    @param: gridSize, tuple, lenght/width or the Workspace.
    @param: shift, to make static error compensation for alignment.
    @param: verbose, boolean, to show the output of the function. 
    ---
    @return: None.
    """
    # Store a deep copy for results:
    roi_copy = roi.copy()

    # Divide the image into a grid:
    verticalCells   = gridSize[1]
    horizontalCells = gridSize[0]

    # Cell dimensions
    bigRectWidth  =  roi_copy.shape[1] 
    bigRectHeight =  roi_copy.shape[0]

    cellWidth = bigRectWidth // horizontalCells
    cellHeight = bigRectHeight // verticalCells

    x_shift, y_shift = shift

    # # Correction values
    origin = mode(roi[y_shift:cellHeight+ y_shift, x_shift:cellWidth+x_shift])
    x_max  = mode(roi[y_shift:y_shift+cellHeight, x_shift+(horizontalCells-1)*cellWidth:x_shift+horizontalCells*cellWidth])
    y_max  = mode(roi[y_shift++(verticalCells-1)*cellHeight:y_shift+verticalCells*cellHeight, x_shift:x_shift+cellWidth])
    print("origin= {}, x_max= {}, y_max= {}".format(origin, x_max, y_max))

    x_corr = ( int(x_max) - int(origin) ) // horizontalCells
    y_corr = ( int(y_max) - int(origin) ) // verticalCells
    print("x_corr = {}, y_corr = {}".format(x_corr, y_corr))

    # Loop thru vertical dimension:
    for j in range(verticalCells):

        # Cell starting y position:
        yo = j * cellHeight + y_shift

        # Loop thru horizontal dimension:
        for i in range(horizontalCells):

            # Cell starting x position:
            xo = i * cellWidth + x_shift

            # Cell Dimensions:
            cX = int(xo)
            cY = int(yo)

            # Quantify current cell:
            # print(i, j, mode(roi[cY:cY + cellHeight, cX:cX + cellWidth]))
            roi_copy[cY:cY + cellHeight, cX:cX + cellWidth] =  mapVal(mode(roi[cY:cY + cellHeight, cX:cX + cellWidth]) - j*y_corr - i*x_corr)# mapVal(371 - mode(roi[cY:cY + cellHeight, cX:cX + cellWidth]))
            # Draw Cell
            cv2.rectangle(roi_copy, (cX, cY), (cX + cellWidth, cY + cellHeight), (100, 100, 255), 1)

    # Visualize results
    if(verbose):
        plt.imshow(roi_copy)
        plt.show()
```

---

So when I try:

```py
path = ""
imName = "d1.png"

d1 = cv2.imread(path+imName, -1)

roi = get_roi(d1, verbose=False)

roi = np.max(roi) - roi

roi[roi<0] = 0
roi[roi>500] = 0

gridWorkspace(roi, verbose=True)
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

Can you please tell me what can I do to improve my segmentation? thanks in advance.

Comment: looks quite good. In what way do you want to improve it?

Comment: @Shai there are some blocks that are not present in this segmentation (at the first level mainly), the red blocks on the external border, for example, are not all present in this segmentation.